# recursivily add characters to the end of the string

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to solve this problem recursively but i am having some issue with the base case . I am unable to come up with the correct base case.

If a word begins with a vowel you just add "way" to the end.

If a word or a cluster of word does not contain a vowel, just add "ay" to the end.

eg:translatePigLatin("california") should return "aliforniacay".

translatePigLatin("glove") should return "oveglay".

translatePigLatin("algorithm") should return "algorithmway".

```js
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  var changed = true;

  if (!["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"].includes(str[0])) {

    return translatePigLatin(str.substring(1, str.length) + str[0])

  }
  else {
    return str + "ay"
  }
}

console.log(translatePigLatin("glove"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
  const chars = str.split('');
  const firstVowel = chars.findIndex(c => vowels.includes(c));
  // words beginning with a vowel are treated differently
  if (firstVowel === 0) {
    return str + 'way';
  } else {
    const start = str.substring(0, firstVowel);
    return str.substring(firstVowel) + start + 'ay';
  } 
}

console.log('glove:', translatePigLatin('glove'));
console.log('california:', translatePigLatin('california'));
console.log('algorithm:', translatePigLatin('algorithm'));
```

Comment: While this gets the right result, it makes no use of recursion at all.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just simply use a flag something like this to differentiate the first call from other recursive call

```js
function translatePigLatin(str, isStart = false) {
  var changed = true;
  
  // to handle case when there's any vowels at start
  if(/^[aeiou]/i.test(str) && isStart){
    return str + 'way'
  }
  
  // to handle case when there's no vowels in string
  if(!/[aeiou]/i.test(str) && isStart){
    return str + 'ay'
  }
 
  if (!["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"].includes(str[0]) ) {
    return translatePigLatin(str.substring(1, str.length) + str[0])
  }
  else {
    return str + "ay"
  }
}

console.log(translatePigLatin("glove", true));
console.log(translatePigLatin("california", true));
console.log(translatePigLatin("algorithm", true));
console.log(translatePigLatin("gypsy", true));
```

Comment: Ahh didn't thought of that case a simple check will fix this

Comment: @Ja͢ck fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

### Update

Ok, a recursive version is not so bad.  And in fact, it might be almost as clean as the original non-recursive solution below.

```js
const toPigLatin = (str, prefix) =>
  (!str) || 'aeiou' .includes (str [0]) 
    ? str + prefix + (prefix.length ? '' : 'w') + 'ay'
    : toPigLatin (str.slice(1), prefix + str[0])

const translatePigLatin = (str) => toPigLatin (str, '')
                            

console .log (['california', 'glove', 'algorithm', 'gypsy'] .map (translatePigLatin))
```

While this could also be written without the helper function, using a default parameter, like this:

```js
const translatePigLatin = (str, prefix = '') =>
  (!str) || 'aeiou' .includes (str [0]) 
    ? str + prefix + (prefix.length ? '' : 'w') + 'ay'
    : translatePigLatin (str.slice(1), prefix + str[0])
```

this would have some strange effects if someone passed additional parameters, as would happen when calling `map` on it.

```js
console .log (['california', 'glove', 'algorithm', 'gypsy'] .map (translatePigLatin))
//=> ["alifornia0cay","ove1glay","algorithm2way","3gypsyay"]
```

You can get around this by wrapping the parameter to `map` in a lambda, like this:

```js
console .log (['california', 'glove', 'algorithm', 'gypsy'] .map (s => translatePigLatin(s)))
//=> ["aliforniacay","oveglay","algorithmway","gypsyay"]
```

But you could never be sure that it won't cause problems.  This is a perennial problem with such default parameters.

#### Update to the update

This alternative might be slightly cleaner:

```js
const toPigLatin = (base, prefix, suffix) =>
  base .length == 0 || 'aeiou' .includes (base [0])
    ? base + prefix + suffix
    : toPigLatin (base .slice (1), prefix + base [0], 'ay')

const translatePigLatin = (str) => toPigLatin (str, '', 'way')
```

### Original Answer

(This became outdated quickly!)

This non-recursive answer seems simpler and more direct than any recursive answer would likely be:

```js
const translatePigLatin = str => {
  const idx = str .split ('') .findIndex (c => 'aeiou' .includes (c))
  return idx == 0
    ? str + 'way'
  : idx < 0
    ? str + 'ay'
  : // else 
    str .slice (idx) + str .slice (0, idx) + 'ay'
}

console .log (['california', 'glove', 'algorithm', 'gypsy'] .map (translatePigLatin))
```

(We might need a `.toLowerCase()` in there as well.)

Are you looking for a recursive solution because you think that will be simpler or because it seems central to the problem?

Comment: Actually i was just trying to get good at solving problems using recursion as i feel i am pretty bad at it.I did solve the problem using  an iterative approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure recursion (meaning the function only uses one parameter), but with the catch that the value returned is a tuple of the three ordered sections of the result: a prefix, possibly the starting consonants that get moved to the suffix, and the final suffix.

```js
function f(s){
  if (s.length == 1){
    if (["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"].includes(s[0]))
      return [s[0], "", "way"];
    else
      return ["", s[0], "ay"];
  }
      
  const n = s.length;
  const [pfx, sfx1, sfx2] = f(s.slice(0, n-1));
  const last = s[n-1];
  
  if (pfx)
    return [pfx + last, sfx1, sfx2];
  else if (["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"].includes(last))
    return [pfx + last, sfx1, sfx2];
  else
    return [pfx, sfx1 + last, sfx2];
}

var strs = [
  "california",
  "glove",
  "algorithm",
  "gypsy"
];

for (let s of strs)
  console.log(s + ": " + JSON.stringify(f(s)));
```

Comment: What makes using only a single parameter more "pure" than any other form of recursion?  Multiple parameters could obviously be wrapped into a single object if necessary, so I see little difference.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I'll let you try to come up with a few ideas yourself.

Comment: Well that sounds condescending!  My answer has a polyadic recursive function that seems just as pure (note that it meets the definition of a pure function) and to me seems simpler than this answer... especially as this one will still need a helper function to get the requested value.

Comment: @ScottSauyet sorry, didn't mean to condescend. We all have ideas and perspectives on things. I was trying to help you get as creative as possible in imagining what *I* could possibly be thinking.

Comment: I'm not much of a mind-reader, I'm afraid.  I asked after I made such an attempt, and after I briefly searched the web for "pure recursion" finding nothing useful.  I hadn't seen the term before and at least as a description for unary recursive function, it doesn't seem to add anything.  I could vaguely imagine somehow using this for a recursive `a -> a` function, but yours is `String -> [String, String, String]`, so that's not it.  So, I think I've done my homework.  Can you tell me what you mean?

Comment: @ScottSauyet to start, a pure recursion does not use the parameters to build the solution. Rather, it uses the result of the previous call.

Comment: @ScottSauyet second, in my interpretation, is that all the information needed is contained in the subsection of the (minimal) input we are examining. Well, and the previous result :)

Comment: I'm afraid that this doesn't make much sense to me.  Presumably the "previous call" used some parameters; the only external information we have in a pure function is passed in as arguments.  I'm curious which of the other recursive solutions here seem "pure" to you.

Comment: @ScottSauyet let's go back to basics - "pure" in my mind, means the function gets one parameter, the string. Period. Derive whatever you like from that in terms of the implications.

Comment: Ah, that makes much more sense to me.  I've usually used "unary" for that, and I've sometimes heard "monadic", although that has other implications for me.  Thank you for bearing with me.

Comment: @ScottSauyet but that's what I explained in parentheses, the first time I mentioned the word, "pure" :)

Comment: It certainly seemed as though the parenthetical remark had to do with "pure recursion" rather than "pure"; that's all.  If I were to write what you meant, I would say something like "a pure (meaning the function only uses one parameter) recursion" rather than placing the parenthetical after the phrase.  That's all.

Comment: @ScottSauyet not sure what difference that would make. Clearly, "pure," stays as an adjective for "recursion," in either instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach the problem with a sliding cursor; everything to the left of this cursor hasn't been processed yet, and on the right are all the consonants. There are two terminal states:

1. The left side starts with a vowel
2. The left side is empty (the word only comprises consonants)

Otherwise, the consonant is moved from the left to the right, and the dance starts all over.

#### Implementation

The inner (named) function is recursive, while the outer function simply configures the initial state for the first call.

```js
function translatePigLatin(s) {
  const vowels = 'aeiou'.split('')

  return function _translate(head, tail) {
    if (head == '' || vowels.includes(head[0])) {
      // head is empty for words without vowels
      // tail is empty on the first pass
      return head + tail + (tail ? 'ay' : 'way');
    }
    // move consonant to the tail
    return _translate(head.slice(1), tail + head[0]);
  }(s, '');
}

const words = [
  'california',
  'glove',
  'algorithm',
  'gypsy'
]
words.forEach(word => console.log(translatePigLatin(word)))
```